# How do I remove all images from slideshow i.e. the Project Resource File in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, image, slideshow, resource-files

[For reference visit the link.
I have tried everything from youtube to the whole Internet.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M2X0qHcOvDCaYOg-w6FETGJVIOGZb83p/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: `Project -> Properties -> Resources -> Images`. Select and `Remove Resource`.

Comment: This questions has no clear explanation, not examples of code tried and results had. Just a link . Do update this and make it a decent question so people can help you better.

Comment: The thing is I have to remove the images from the project resource file